# String lowercase equality (newbie question)

Tags: expansion, strings

i'd like to test if a string, once transformed into lowercase is equal to a given string. Here a MWE of what i'm talking about :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\begin{document} 

\def\planeone{AirForce1}
\def\planetwo{airforce1}
\edef\planethree{\lowercase{\planeone}}

\planetwo{ and  }\planethree{ are }
\ifx\planetwo\planethree{the same}\else{not the same}\fi.

\end{document}
```

Of course when i test `\meaning\planetwo` and `\meaning\planethree` i can see the two commands are not the same, but i just want to test what they expand to.

I tried a few `\expandafter` here and there, but without any success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\lowercase` is not expandable, so you're doing the same as

```
\def\planethree{\lowercase{AirForce1}}
```

and therefore `\planethree` is different from `\planetwo`.

You can do

```
\lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\planethree\expandafter{\planeone}}
```

but a different strategy can be better for more complex situations:

```
\begingroup\edef\x{%
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand\planethree{\planeone}}}%
\x
```

With this code you delay the application of `\lowercase` when the replacement text for `\planethree` has already been completely expanded.

Let's see how it works.

1. The `\begingroup` is used just to set a temporary value to `\x`
2. We `\edef` the macro `\x`, so `\planeone` will be completely expanded as it should, but `\lowercase`, `\def` and `\planethree` are left untouched
3. After the `\edef`, the replacement text of `\x` will be

   ```
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def\planethree{Airforce1}}
   ```
4. Executing `\x` will do the `\lowercase` that will change the case of the letters
5. After that operation,

   ```
   \endgroup\def\planethree{airforce1}
   ```

   is put back in the main input stream, so the group started with `\begingroup` is ended and the definition is performed.